# Remove the price(xx.00) from a set of sting where xx can be from 0 - 1000s

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to remove all the price from my text

eg.

> "CVC 50/50 Flat Sheet: 250 74 x 110 Plain  1.00      10   10.00"

i want to remove every prices in the text in order to have only the quantity number

> "CVC 50/50 Flat Sheet: 250 74 x 110 Plain   10"

i tried

```
str_replace('(i don't know what to put here).00',' ',$Body)
```

Please assist with some str_replace pattern or something that will fix this problem.

Many thanks!!

P.s. The prices are vary from 0.00 to xxxxx.00

Comment: Are the prices always the third last and last 'tokens' in the text?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead which makes the matching fairly straight forward;

```
$a = "CVC 50/50 Flat Sheet: 250 74 x 110 Plain 1.00 10 10.00";

echo preg_replace('/\s\d+\.00/', '', $a);    // whitespace+digits+.00 -> ''

>> CVC 50/50 Flat Sheet: 250 74 x 110 Plain 10
```